# How can I select values from two columns in two different tables in Codeignter?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to get (**category_name** in '**user_albums table**) & (**image_name** in '**user_images table**). Each user's album has a been assigned a **category_id**. Each image has been assigned a **category_id**(basically same id) based on the album they were uploaded to. I am using Codeigniter framework

I am getting this records using the codeigniter join query.Find my code below

**Here is my model**

```
public function get_user_albums()
{
    $id = $this->session->userdata('id');
    $this->db->select('user_albums.category_name, user_images.image_name');
    $this->db->from('user_albums');
    $this->db->join('user_images', 'user_albums.category_id 
    =user_images.category_id');
    $this->db->where('user_albums.user_id', $id);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

My challenge is that whenever I try getting the category_names to view,category_name is printed for each images i uploaded.

So basically if I created album named **'Test'** and uploaded **two** images rock.jpg and wow.jpg.

When I try printing out **(category_name) which is 'Test'**, I ended up printing out Test **twice** while essentially it should be printed only **once**.
Where could I be getting this wrong?

Comment: Please provide your tables always as text.

Comment: @Erick Kibet In your code was missing curly bracte after the end of the function , i updated the code of you function now please use. Thanks!!